# Design strategy for Microservices in .NET

Tags: microservices

What would be a good way for Microservices .NET to communicate with each other? Would a peer to peer communication be better (for performance) using NETMQ (port of ZeroMQ) or would it be better via a Bus (NServiceBus or  RhinoBus)?
Also would you break up your data access layer into microservices too?

-Indu

Comment: You may want to **read whathaveyoutried.com & show some respect** to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a **MCVE ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far**. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Comment: I am still deciding on a design strategy and am looking for recommendations.

Comment: It would be rather a **highly-misleading** technology marketing to provide any kind of such **"recommendation"** if it were not based on quantitative evidence (read as test, test and again a test to validate that **all design criteria** were met). Better get more quantitative beforehand. Transport related trivialities alike max. permitted e-2-e latency [ns], min/max size [B], min. aggregate throughput [Mmsg/s] will soon get less important than architecture capabilities - Control-Plane(s), sync/async/non-blocking atomic patterns and internal signalling, external use-case's scaleability. T.B.C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Service Bus-based design allows your application to leverage the [decoupling middleware](http://screamingtiger.blogspot.ie/2010/04/release-it-chapter-58-decoupling.html) design pattern. You have explicit control in terms of how each Microservice communicates. You can also throttle traffic. However, it really depends on your requirements. Please refer to [this tutorial](http://insidethecpu.com/2015/07/17/microservices-in-c-part-1-building-and-testing/) on building and testing Microservices in .NET (C#).

Answer (score 0):

We are starting down this same path.  Like all new hot new methodologies, you must be careful that you are actually achieving the benefits of using a Microservices approach.

We have evaluated [Azure Service Fabric](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-fabric/) as one possibility.  As a place to host your applications it seems quite promising.  There is also an impressive API if you want your applications to tightly integrate with the environment.  This integration could likely answer your questions.  The caveat is that the API is still in flux (it's improving) and documentation is scarce.  It also feels a bit like "vendor lock".

To keep things simple, we have started out by letting our microservices be simple stateless applications that communicate via REST.  The endpoints are well-documented and contain a contract version number as part of the URI.  We intend to introduce more sophisticated ways of interaction later as the need arises (ie, performance).

To answer your question about "data access layer", my opinion would be that each microservice should persist state in whatever way is best for that service to do so.  The actual storage is private to the microservices and other services may only use that data through its public API.

Comment: Can we develop microservice architecture without azure service fabric?

Comment: @AdityaBokade yes of course. You can build them using ASP.NET Core Web API. For orchestration, you can leverage Kubernetes or AKS. Reference implementation here: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

Answer (score -1):

We've recently open sourced our .NET microservices framework, that covers a couple of the needed patterns for microservices. I recommend at least taking a look to understand what is needed when you go into this kind of architecture. 
https://github.com/gigya/microdot